# SQL Filter criteria in join criteria or where clause which is more efficient

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, where-clause

I have a relatively simple query joining two tables.  The "Where" criteria can be expressed either in the join criteria or as a where clause.  I'm wondering which is more efficient.

Query is to find max sales for a salesman from the beginning of time until they were promoted.

Case 1

```
select salesman.salesmanid, max(sales.quantity)
from salesman
inner join sales  on salesman.salesmanid =sales.salesmanid 
                  and sales.salesdate < salesman.promotiondate
group by salesman.salesmanid
```

Case 2

```
select salesman.salesmanid, max(sales.quantity)
from salesman
inner join sales  on salesman.salesmanid =sales.salesmanid 
where sales.salesdate < salesman.promotiondate
group by salesman.salesmanid
```

Note Case 1 lacks a where clause altogether

RDBMS is Sql Server 2005

**EDIT**
If the second piece of the join criteria or the where clause was sales.salesdate < some fixed date so its not actually any criteria of joining the two tables does that change the answer.

Comment: What's wrong with actually testing the time these queries take?

Comment: Because the query's get cached but thanks, really

Comment: @Gratzy -- DBCC FREEPROCCACHE  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174283.aspx

Comment: @Gratzy -- just so you get this.  There's a book specific to SQL Server 2000 that may get to the depths you want (unsure about a 2005 edition)  http://www.amazon.com/Gurus-Guide-Server-Architecture-Internals/dp/0201700476

Comment: We are executing one SQL statement in a union based on the value of the stored procedure parameter.  Currently the SQL tests the parameter value in the where clause. Is it better to have the test on the inner join?  I thought it might be useful to explore if this an occasion where the usage is important?  There are separate references for join (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and where (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/where-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) but not a discussion about which is executed first?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I wouldn't use performance as the deciding factor here - and quite honestly, I don't think there's any measurable performance difference between those two cases, really.

I would always use case #2 - why? Because in my opinion, you should only put the actual criteria that establish the JOIN between the two tables into the JOIN clause - everything else belongs in the WHERE clause.

Just a matter of keeping things clean and put things where they belong, IMO.

Obviously, there are cases with LEFT OUTER JOINs where the placement of the criteria does make a difference in terms of what results get returned - those cases would be excluded from my recommendation, of course.

Marc

Comment: IMO one could argue that case #1 is better for encapsulation (in this case, WHERE clause is only used for main table criteria).

Answer (score 4):

One thing I want to say finally as I notified, before that..
Both ways may give the same performance or using the criteria at **Where** clause may be little faster as found in some answers..

But I identified one difference, you can use for your logical needs..

1. Using the criteria at **ON** clause will not filter/skip the rows to select instead the join columns would be null based on the conditions
2. Using  the criteria at **Where** clause may filter/skip the rows at the entire results

Answer (score 3):

You can run the execution plan estimator and sql profiler to see how they stack up against each other.

However, they are semantically the same underneath the hood according to this SQL Server MVP:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/conversation.aspx?messageid=29145383&threadid=29145379

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: The answer is eight years old so I'm not too surprised.  The performance issue is still answered in that they are the same.  However, the join syntax has long been the standard for clarity as @marc_s writes in his answer.  Keep the where clause for non join criteria.

Comment: There are other reasons that change the result if you add criteria in the join e.g. regarding left joins. Please see this rather helpful blog post: https://www.sqlteam.com/articles/additional-criteria-in-the-join-clause

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to have any hard coded criteria in the join. It makes the SQL much more readable and portable.

Readability:
You can see exactly what data you're going to get because all the table criteria is written right there in the join. In large statements, the criteria may be buried within 50 other expressions and is easily missed.

Portability:
You can just copy a chunk out of the FROM clause and paste it somewhere else. That gives the joins and any criteria you need to go with it. If you always use that criteria when joining those two tables, then putting it in the join is the most logical.

For Example:

```
FROM
table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2_ABC ON
  t1.c1 = t2_ABC.c1 AND
  t2_ABC.c2 = 'ABC'
```

If you need to get a second column out of table 2 you just copy that block into Notepad, search/repalce "ABC" and presto and entire new block of code ready to paste back in.

Additional:
It's also easier to change between an inner and outer join without having to worry about any criteria that may be floating around in the WHERE clause.

I reserve the WHERE clause strictly for run-time criteria where possible.

As for efficiency:
If you're referring to excecution speed, then as everyone else has stated, it's redundant.
If you're referring to easier debugging and reuse, then I prefer option 1.

Comment: To summarize, criteria in the JOIN is better for encapsulation, and increased encapsulation is usually better.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll find a finite answer for this one that applies to all cases.  The 2 are not always interchangeable - since for some queries (some left joins) you will come up with different results by placing the criteria in the WHERE vs the FROM line.

In your case, you should evaluate both of these queries.  In SSMS, you can view the estimated and actual execution plans of both of these queries - that would be a good first step in determining which is more optimal.  You could also view the time & IO for each (set statistics time on, set statistics io on) - and that will also give you information to make your decision.

In the case of the queries in your question - I'd bet that they'll both come out with the same query plan - so in this case it may not matter, but in others it could potentially produce different plans.

Try this to see the difference between the 2...

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON
SET STATISTICS TIME ON

select salesman.salesmanid, 
       max(sales.quantity)
from   salesmaninner join sales on salesman.salesmanid =sales.salesmanid
       and sales.salesdate < salesman.promotiondate
group by salesman.salesmanid

select salesman.salesmanid, 
       max(sales.quantity)
from   salesmaninner join sales on salesman.salesmanid = sales.salesmanid 
where  sales.salesdate < salesman.promotiondate
group by salesman.salesmanid

SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
SET STATISTICS IO OFF
```

Comment: This would be specifically inner joins

Comment: Gratzy - in that case, I agree with marc_s - the filter criteria should be kept in the WHERE portion of the query, and the join criteria should be kept in the FROM portion of the query.

Comment: Does it matter though that the where criteria table has many, many more rows.  I know that may sound trivial but I was wondering if it then would be better to make it part of the join criteria instead of the where clause

Comment: I don't think that should have any impact - but I'd still suggest looking at the plans generated for both queries.  In general, i think your code will be easier to read if you keep the filter and join criteria separate.  In practice, that might not always be possible - but given identical query plans, i'd always choose the 2nd query for readability.

Answer (score 0):

It may seem flippant, but the answer is whichever query for which the query analyzer produces the most efficient plan.

To my mind, they seem to be equivalent, so the query analyzer may well produce identical plans, but you'd have to test.

Answer (score 0):

Neither is more efficient, using the WHERE method is considered the old way to do so (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014.aspx). YOu can look at the execution plan and see they do the same thing.

Comment: My example wasn't the best change the second part of the join and or where clause to be a fixed date instead of a date in the salesman table.

Comment: Ahh okay, well in either case the Execution Plan is your friend. Analyze it to find which one has the best performance. My bet is they'll be identical.

Answer (score 0):

Become familiar with the Estimated Execution Plan in SQL Management Studio!!  Like others have said, you're at the mercy of the analyzer no matter what you do so trust its estimates.  I would guess the two you provided would produce the exact same plan.

If it's an attempt to change a development culture, pick the one that gives you a better plan; for the ones that are identical, follow the culture

I've commented this on other "efficiency" posts like this one (it's both sincere and sarcastic) -- if this is where your bottlenecks reside, then high-five to you and your team.

Comment: Yes I am familiar with Estimated Execution Plan.  It however will not tell me why it generates the execution plan the way it does.  I was looking to understand why one might be more efficient than the other.

Comment: @Gratzy:  http://www.amazon.com/Gurus-Guide-Server-Architecture-Internals/dp/0201700476

Answer (score 0):

Case 1 (criteria in the JOIN) is better for encapsulation, and increased encapsulation is usually a good thing: decreased copy/paste omissions to another query, decreased bugs if later converted to LEFT JOIN, and increased readability (related stuff together and less "noise" in WHERE clause).  In this case, the WHERE clause only captures principal table criteria or criteria that spans multiple tables.