# Which SQL query is faster? Filter on Join criteria or Where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Compare these 2 queries. Is it faster to put the filter on the join criteria or in the `WHERE` clause. I have always felt that it is faster on the join criteria because it reduces the result set at the soonest possible moment, but I don't know for sure.

I'm going to build some tests to see, but I also wanted to get opinions on which would is clearer to read as well.

**Query 1**

```
SELECT      *
FROM        TableA a
INNER JOIN  TableXRef x
        ON  a.ID = x.TableAID
INNER JOIN  TableB b
        ON  x.TableBID = b.ID
WHERE       a.ID = 1            /* <-- Filter here? */
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT      *
FROM        TableA a
INNER JOIN  TableXRef x
        ON  a.ID = x.TableAID
        AND a.ID = 1            /* <-- Or filter here? */
INNER JOIN  TableB b
        ON  x.TableBID = b.ID
```

**EDIT**

I ran some tests and the results show that it is actually very close, but the `WHERE` clause is actually slightly faster! =)

I absolutely agree that it makes more sense to apply the filter on the `WHERE` clause, I was just curious as to the performance implications.

**ELAPSED TIME WHERE CRITERIA:** 143016 ms
**ELAPSED TIME JOIN CRITERIA:** 143256 ms

**TEST**

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @num    INT,
        @iter   INT

SELECT  @num    = 1000, -- Number of records in TableA and TableB, the cross table is populated with a CROSS JOIN from A to B
        @iter   = 1000  -- Number of select iterations to perform

DECLARE @a TABLE (
        id INT
)

DECLARE @b TABLE (
        id INT
)

DECLARE @x TABLE (
        aid INT,
        bid INT
)

DECLARE @num_curr INT
SELECT  @num_curr = 1
        
WHILE (@num_curr <= @num)
BEGIN
    INSERT @a (id) SELECT @num_curr
    INSERT @b (id) SELECT @num_curr
    
    SELECT @num_curr = @num_curr + 1
END

INSERT      @x (aid, bid)
SELECT      a.id,
            b.id
FROM        @a a
CROSS JOIN  @b b

/*
    TEST
*/
DECLARE @begin_where    DATETIME,
        @end_where      DATETIME,
        @count_where    INT,
        @begin_join     DATETIME,
        @end_join       DATETIME,
        @count_join     INT,
        @curr           INT,
        @aid            INT

DECLARE @temp TABLE (
        curr    INT,
        aid     INT,
        bid     INT
)

DELETE FROM @temp

SELECT  @curr   = 0,
        @aid    = 50

SELECT  @begin_where = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHILE (@curr < @iter)
BEGIN
    INSERT      @temp (curr, aid, bid)
    SELECT      @curr,
                aid,
                bid
    FROM        @a a
    INNER JOIN  @x x
            ON  a.id = x.aid
    INNER JOIN  @b b
            ON  x.bid = b.id
    WHERE       a.id = @aid
        
    SELECT @curr = @curr + 1
END
SELECT  @end_where = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

SELECT  @count_where = COUNT(1) FROM @temp
DELETE FROM @temp

SELECT  @curr = 0
SELECT  @begin_join = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHILE (@curr < @iter)
BEGIN
    INSERT      @temp (curr, aid, bid)
    SELECT      @curr,
                aid,
                bid
    FROM        @a a
    INNER JOIN  @x x
            ON  a.id = x.aid
            AND a.id = @aid
    INNER JOIN  @b b
            ON  x.bid = b.id
    
    SELECT @curr = @curr + 1
END
SELECT  @end_join = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

SELECT  @count_join = COUNT(1) FROM @temp
DELETE FROM @temp

SELECT  @count_where AS count_where,
        @count_join AS count_join,
        DATEDIFF(millisecond, @begin_where, @end_where) AS elapsed_where,
        DATEDIFF(millisecond, @begin_join, @end_join) AS elapsed_join
```

Comment: Depending on data, WHERE vs JOIN criteria can return different resultsets.

Comment: @OMG Ponies very true, but a lot of times it doesn't as well.

Comment: I would not call  difference beelow 5% as a difference- they are the same. You want significance for a 2 %% difference better run the tests 1000 times to make sure iti s not just random.

Comment: The benefit is in filtering the data before joining so if it was x.ID then you would be more likely to see improvement than with an a.ID

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Filter criteria in join criteria or where clause which is more efficient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401889/sql-filter-criteria-in-join-criteria-or-where-clause-which-is-more-efficient)

Comment: @OMGPonies Putting a condition in WHERE  vs ON, assuming names are in scope, can only make a result set difference when there are outer joins.

Comment: I think there are some complex or fringe cases where it does make a difference. I've had situations where the where clause query runs for minutes, but the join criteria query is instant. It's relatively rare in my experience - and I've never been able to tell what was going on.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Performance-wise, they are the same (and produce the same plans)

Logically, you should make the operation that still has sense if you replace `INNER JOIN` with a `LEFT JOIN`.

In your very case this will look like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TableA a
LEFT JOIN
        TableXRef x
ON      x.TableAID = a.ID
        AND a.ID = 1
LEFT JOIN
        TableB b
ON      x.TableBID = b.ID
```

or this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TableA a
LEFT JOIN
        TableXRef x
ON      x.TableAID = a.ID
LEFT JOIN
        TableB b
ON      b.id = x.TableBID
WHERE   a.id = 1
```

The former query will not return any actual matches for `a.id` other than `1`, so the latter syntax (with `WHERE`) is logically more consistent.

Comment: When I draw the sets I understood why the second case is more consistent. In the former query, the constraint `a.id = 1` applies only for the intersection, not the left part excluding the intersection.

Comment: In the first example there may be rows where `a.id != 1`, the other will only have rows where `a.id = 1`.

Comment: Your language is unclear. "Logically, you should make the operation that still has sense if ..." and "logically more consistent" don't make sense. Can  you please rephrase?

Answer (score 35):

For inner joins it doesn't matter where you put your criteria. The SQL compiler will transform both into an execution plan in which the filtering occurs below the join (ie. as if the filter expressions appears is in the join condition).

Outer joins are a different matter, since the place of the filter changes the semantics of the query.

Comment: So in inner joins it first calculates the filter and then joins the output of the filter with the other table or does it first join the two tables and then apply the filter?

Comment: @Remus Rusanu - could you please elaborate on how the semantics gets changed in case of Outer-join ?  I get different results based on the position of the filter, but unable to understand why

Comment: @Ananth with an outer join you get NULLs for all columns of the joined table where the JOIN condition does not match. Filters will not satisfy the NULL and eliminate the rows, turning the OUTER join in effect into an INNER join.

Comment: @Ananth I achieved my required optimizations based on your comment.  My change was from WHERE x.TableAID = a.ID or x.TableAID is null  to ON x.TableAID = a.ID.  Changing the location of the filter on an OUTER join let the compiler know to Filter then Join rather than Join then Filter.  It was also able to use the index on that column because it didn't have to match Null.  Query response changed from 61 seconds to 2 seconds.

Answer (score 9):

As far as the two methods go.

- JOIN/ON is for joining tables
- WHERE is for filtering results

Whilst you can use them differently it always seems like a smell to me.

Deal with performance when it is a problem. Then you can look into such "optimisations".

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

With any query optimizer worh a cent.... they are identical.

Comment: I'm quite sure that, with any real workload, they are not identical. If you almost don't have data, then the question is worthless.

Comment: Check it out under real workload. Basically - if they generate the same execution plan, they... are identical in performance.

At least for normal / simple cases (i.e. not the one joining 14 tables) I am quite sure they are identical ;)

Answer (score 3):

In postgresql they are the same. We know this because if you do `explain analyze` on each of the queries, the plan comes out to be the same. Take this example:

```
# explain analyze select e.* from event e join result r on e.id = r.event_id and r.team_2_score=24;

                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Join  (cost=27.09..38.22 rows=7 width=899) (actual time=0.045..0.047 rows=1 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (e.id = r.event_id)
   ->  Seq Scan on event e  (cost=0.00..10.80 rows=80 width=899) (actual time=0.009..0.010 rows=2 loops=1)
   ->  Hash  (cost=27.00..27.00 rows=7 width=8) (actual time=0.017..0.017 rows=1 loops=1)
         Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
         ->  Seq Scan on result r  (cost=0.00..27.00 rows=7 width=8) (actual time=0.006..0.008 rows=1 loops=1)
               Filter: (team_2_score = 24)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 1
 Planning time: 0.182 ms
 Execution time: 0.101 ms
(10 rows)

# explain analyze select e.* from event e join result r on e.id = r.event_id where r.team_2_score=24;
                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Join  (cost=27.09..38.22 rows=7 width=899) (actual time=0.027..0.029 rows=1 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (e.id = r.event_id)
   ->  Seq Scan on event e  (cost=0.00..10.80 rows=80 width=899) (actual time=0.010..0.011 rows=2 loops=1)
   ->  Hash  (cost=27.00..27.00 rows=7 width=8) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)
         Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
         ->  Seq Scan on result r  (cost=0.00..27.00 rows=7 width=8) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=1 loops=1)
               Filter: (team_2_score = 24)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 1
 Planning time: 0.140 ms
 Execution time: 0.058 ms
(10 rows)
```

They both have the same min and max cost as well as the same query plan. Also, notice that even in the top query the team_score_2 gets applied as a 'Filter'.

Answer (score 1):

Rule #0: Run some benchmarks and see! The only way to really tell which will  be faster is to try it. These types of benchmarks are very easy to perform using the SQL profiler.

Also, examine the execution plan for the query written with a JOIN and with a WHERE clause to see what differences stand out.

Finally, as others have said, these two should be treated identically by any decent optimizer, including the one built into SQL Server.

Comment: But only for inner joins. The results set will be very different for out joins.

Comment: Of course. Fortunately, the provided example uses inner joins.

Comment: Unfortunetly the question is about joins, not inner joins.

Comment: Yes David, the question is about joins. The sample supporting the question happens to use inner joins.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the first, because it makes a more specific filter over the data. But you [should see the execution plan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms979196.aspx), as with any optimization, because it can be very different deppending on size of data, server hardware, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Is it faster? Try it and see.

Which is easier to read? The first to me looks more "correct", as the moved condition is nothing really to do with the join.

Answer (score 0):

It is really unlikely that the placement of this join will be the deciding factor for performance. I am not intimately familiar with the execution planning for tsql, but it's likely that they will be optimized automatically to similar plans.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is meant for those landing here for ***optimising queries with joins*** on large databases.

As most answers suggest, filtering in join criteria does make significant difference in performance. In some cases, **joins can be avoided**. ORMs (Object-Relational Mapping) like that of **Django** framework generate queries with table joins when querying fields from related tables. If we are already **paginating** the results, **avoiding these joins** altogether will make significant difference in performance.

consider a **`Message`** table which has foreign keys `thread` (to `Thread` table) `sender` (to `User` table) and `topic` (to `Topic` table)

```python
msgs = Message.filter(content__icontains=keyword).values('id','msg_type','thread',
'thread__title','thread__created','created','sender__name','sender__email',
'attachment','permalink','is_marked','topic__title','topic__admin__name',
'topic__created','topic__description').order_by('-is_marked','-id')
```

The above queryset creates a query that have joins on models (tables) `Topic`, `Thread` and `Sender`. All that we need to get are messages containing the keyword and get fields `name` from `Sender`, `title` from `Thread` table etc.

A search along with all these joins will be way too slow.

Instead, splitting the query like the following will be much faster:

```python
# fetching only fields from Message table
msgs = Message.filter(content__icontains=keyword).values('id','msg_type','thread','created',
'sender','attachment','permalink','is_marked','topic').order_by('-is_marked','-id')

# paginating the results
paginator = Paginator(msgs,100)
page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    items = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    items = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    items = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

# getting primary keys of records to fetch from Thread, User, Topic tables
thread_ids,sender_ids,topic_ids = set(),set(),set()
items.object_list = list(items.object_list)
for msg in items.object_list:
    thread_ids.add(msg['thread'])
    sender_ids.add(msg['sender'])
    topic_ids.add(msg['topic'])

# Fetching only the required records from Thread, User, Topic tables
thread_details = {i['id']:i for i in Thread.objects.filter(id__in=thread_ids).values('id','title','created') }
sender_details = {i[0]:i for i in User.objects.filter(id__in=sender_ids).values('id','name','email') }
topic_details = {i['id']:i for i in Topic.objects.filter(id__in=topic_ids).values('id','title','created') }

# saving the fetched data to the results
for msg in items.object_list:
    t = thread_details.get(msg['thread'],{})
    msg['thread_title'] = t.get('title')
    msg['thread_created'] = t.get('created')

    s = sender_details.get(msg['sender'],{})
    msg['sender_name'] = sender_details.get('name','')
    msg['sender_email'] = sender_details.get('email','')

    t = topic_details.get(msg['topic'],{})
    msg['topic_title'] = t.get('title')
    msg['topic_created'] = t.get('created')

print(items.object_list)
```

Here, the joins are avoided at database level and done with python code. This works if you are not sorting or filtering using any field in the related models

Note: this is not useful unless your table has million of records

Comment: This answers a completely different question, specific to the way an application is designed. If you have lookup data then yes, it's cheaper to cache it instead of retrieving it from the database every time.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos
i just gave and example from django. The example is specific but the problem is not specific to django. when we have to search in a table with large number of entries, but also want to fetch fields from related tables, avoiding joins will be effective. Giving an example in python or django doesn't make it specfic to python or django

Comment: This is not a direct answer for the question. I landed in this page bcoz of a scenario like the one i described. I was trying to optimise the query, and i ended up totally avoiding the joins. I think that all the views of this page (question) is not out of curiosity about the performance comparison of `where` clause and  filter criteria on `join`. Many are trying to optimize their query