# Are these SQL queries identical - if not whats the difference

Tags: mysql, sql

Assuming the proper tables are in place - what is the difference between the two queries - when would they return different results

```
select *
from quiz_user qu
join quiz_topic qt on qu.quiz_id = qt.quiz_id and qt.topic_id=44
where qu.user_id=9

select *
from quiz_user qu
join quiz_topic qt on qu.quiz_id = qt.quiz_id 
where qu.user_id=9
and qt.topic_id=44
```

Thanks

Comment: please see the link.. cheers..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509987/which-sql-query-is-faster-filter-on-join-criteria-or-where-clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any difference in queries as they are. However, if you used `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER` (default), results would be different.

Comment: Thanks - so if the query was a left join then how would the results differ

Comment: @Gublooo: In case of `LEFT JOIN` you will very likely get more rows (all rows from `quiz_user` will be included in resultset regardless of whether corresponding rows in `quiz_topic` exist or not)

Answer (score 2):

None, but the second code's intent is clearer, JOIN is merely used to reflect the data relationship, not for filtering.

On first code's JOIN, it would seem the number 44 has a bearing on quiz_topic's relationship to quiz_user

Comment: Thanks - yep agree with u - not a good idea to use join to specify filter conditions