# JOIN not work with where

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this code :

```
select
  B.plc_nomeConta, B.plc_classificador, B.plc_id,
  A.cap_idPlanoContasFin, SUM(A.cap_valorfatura) as Total     
from
  tbl_PlanoFinanceiro B
  left outer join erp_contaspagar A on B.plc_id = A.cap_idPlanoContasFin
   /*  where A.cap_idEmpresa like 2*/
group by
  B.plc_nomeConta,
  B.plc_classificador,
  B.plc_id,
  A.cap_idPlanoContasFin
```

This code returns 185 Lines,

```
(-) COFINS     10.01.01.01.004  330  330   971090,97
(-) ICMS       10.01.01.01.002  328  328   1378407,11
(-) IMPOSTOS   10.01.00.00.000  324  NULL  NULL
(-) IMPOSTOS   10.01.01.00.000  325  NULL  NULL
(-) IMPOSTOS   10.01.01.01.000  326  NULL  NULL
(-) ISS        10.01.01.01.001  327  327   1000960,59
(-) PIS        10.01.01.01.003  329  329   240600,27
```

but when I uncomment the `where  /*  where A.cap_idEmpresa like 2*/`, returns only the lines where  `A.cap_idPlanoContasFin is not null`, In need ever `B.plc_nomeConta, B.plc_classificador, B.plc_id` appears.

Comment: Try `AND` instead of `WHERE`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `WHERE` filter is converting the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`.

Essentially you are saying "Show me all records on the left, and only records on the right that match AND have a `cap_idEmpresa` value of `2`".

This means you are only showing matching records, which is an `INNER JOIN` -- any unmatched records cannot have a value of `2` in that field.

To correct you either need to account for null:

`WHERE (A.cap_idEmpresa like 2 OR A.cap_idEmpresa IS NULL)`

or refine your requirements.

Comment: Alternatively, you could move `A.cap_idEmpresa like 2` to be part of the join.

Comment: @cadrell0 Adding a value check to an `OUTER JOIN` will change the logic of the `JOIN`, though.

Comment: @JNK to be fair, I can't properly interpret the actual requirements. I can't even blame it on being a Monday.

Comment: @JNK The results set produced either way should be identical.  I'm not sure which will have the more efficient execution plan, if that is what you mean.

Comment: @cadrell0 they are semantically different: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509987/which-sql-query-is-faster-filter-on-join-criteria-or-where-clause

Comment: @JNK I think they are semantically different if you do a direct swap. The way you've structured your WHERE clause with the OR makes it semantically equivalent to making the conditional part of the join.

Comment: I have solve with JNK and cadrell0 , making the A.Cap_idempresa like 2 being part of the JOin , thanks by the here the code

Answer (score 0):

I have solve with JNK and cadrell0 , making the A.Cap_idempresa like 2 being part of the JOin , thanks by the here the code

```
        alter proc Ntrimestre (@emp integer,@inicio datetime,@fim datetime) as
        select  B.plc_nomeConta, B.plc_classificador ,B.plc_id ,
        A.cap_idPlanoContasFin, SUM (A.cap_valorfatura) as Total
        from tbl_PlanoFinanceiro B
        left outer join erp_contaspagar A on B.plc_id = A.cap_idPlanoContasFin 
        and   A.cap_idEmpresa like @emp
        and A.cap_vencfatura <= convert(datetime,@fim,1) 
        and cap_vencfatura >= convert(datetime,@inicio,1) 
        group by B.plc_nomeConta, B.plc_classificador ,B.plc_id, A.cap_idPlanoContasFin
       order by B.plc_classificador
```

The other way with where :

```
       alter proc NtrimestreMzFSant (@inicio datetime,@fim datetime) as
       select  B.plc_nomeConta, B.plc_classificador ,B.plc_id ,
        A.cap_idPlanoContasFin, SUM (A.cap_valorfatura) as Total
       from tbl_PlanoFinanceiro B
       left outer join erp_contaspagar A on B.plc_id = A.cap_idPlanoContasFin  
        and A.cap_vencfatura <= convert(datetime,@fim,1) 
         and A.cap_vencfatura >= convert(datetime,@inicio,1) 
        where B.plc_tipo <> 'Sintética' and A.cap_idEmpresa =2 or A.cap_idEmpresa=2234 
        group by B.plc_nomeConta, B.plc_classificador ,B.plc_id, A.cap_idPlanoContasFin
        order by B.plc_classificador
```

Thanks every body by the help