# Where clause with multiple OR

Tags: mysql, sql

I was trying to access list of foods with which has restaurant_id = 2 and if the food_id in carts table it should print cart_id and if the food_id in favorites table it should print favorite_id otherwise it will return null. But the problem i'm facing here is food_id i'm getting from that specific restaurant but while checking the carts and favorites id it fails to check for the user_id.

food_id is in the carts table but not for that user but it shows that cart_id. How do i make the query correct?

```
Foods table: id, restaurant_id
Carts Table: id, user_id, food_id
Favorites Table: id, user_id, food_id
```

**SQL QUERY:**

```
SELECT foods.id, carts.id as cart_id , favorites.id as favorite_id 
FROM foods 
LEFT JOIN carts 
ON carts.food_id= foods.id 
LEFT JOIN favorites 
ON favorites.food_id= foods.id 
WHERE foods.restaurant_id = 2 
AND (carts.user_id = 1 OR favorites.user_id = 1)
```

Comment: Sample data and expected result is appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34454867/difference-between-filtering-queries-in-join-and-where

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use something like this:

```
SELECT foods.id, carts.id as cart_id, favorites.id as favorite_id
FROM foods
left join carts on carts.food_id=foods.id and carts.user_id = 1
LEFT JOIN favorites on favorites.food_id=foods.id and favorites.user_id = 1
WHERE foods.restaurant_id = 2
```

note that you need to filter both tables (cards/favorites) by user id