# SQL Server - performance for filtering using LEFT JOIN ON condition versus WHERE condition

Tags: sql-server, performance, join, left-join

I have a query that was performing slowly that looked something like this:

```
DECLARE @TeamId INT = 123
...
SELECT
...
FROM Player p
LEFT JOIN PlayerTeam pt ON p.PlayerId = pt.PlayerId
...
WHERE pt.TeamId = @TeamId
...
```

The PlayerTeam table has a large numer of records (ie. 30 million)

When I modified the query to have the condition on the left join instead of the where clause, then the query peformed much better.

```
DECLARE @TeamId INT = 123
...
SELECT
...
FROM Player p
LEFT JOIN PlayerTeam pt ON p.PlayerId = pt.PlayerId AND pt.TeamId = @TeamId
...
```

Is this a correct optimization and is the peformance improvement expected? I read that this shouldn't matter when using an inner join, but for a left join it seems to make a difference.

[Which sql query is faster filter on join criteria or where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509987/which-sql-query-is-faster-filter-on-join-criteria-or-where-clause)

Comment: You're comparing apples and oranges.  These queries yield different results.  In your first example all the nulls generated by the left join are subsequently eliminated by the where clause; making the left join behave like an inner join.  In the second example the nulls are retained. So 1st should be slower since the left join must match all players for all teams then limit by team.  The 2nd query limits by team and matches at the same level; thus can be more efficient if proper indexes are in place. so, "Is this a correct optimization and is the performance improvement expected?" Yes expected

Comment: Read a definition of left join. It returns inner join rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. You cannot in general move conditions between an outer join on condition & a where. In cases where it doesn't matter, a DBMS optimizer typically can tell they are equivalent. The highest-voted answer you link to talks about left joins, but it is (currently) unintelligible. Read re query implementation. PS This is both basic & a faq. Please before asking google many clear, concise, specific variations of your question and read many hits. If you don't get an answer, use one as title.