# Converting deprecated outer join operators in SQL server, *= to left join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to convert an old query from the deprecated *= to the left join statement.
I am not particularly familiar with the old operator, and I'm not sure if the query I'm trying to convert is badly written, or if that's the correct notation. I'll try to explain what I mean:

```
SELECT GivenName, Surname, OrderNumber
FROM Customers, SalesOrders
WHERE Customers.ID *= SalesOrders.CustomerID
and SalesOrders.OrderNumber = 1000 -- ???
```

Is OrderNumber = 1000 part of the left join?
If OrderNumber is not part of the left join, then the use of the *= operator seems pointless.

Or, in other terms, which is the equivalent code:

```
SELECT GivenName, Surname, OrderNumber
FROM Customers LEFT JOIN SalesOrders
ON Customers.ID = SalesOrders.CustomerID 
and SalesOrders.OrderNumber = 1000
```

or

```
SELECT GivenName, Surname, OrderNumber
FROM Customers LEFT JOIN SalesOrders
ON Customers.ID = SalesOrders.CustomerID 
WHERE SalesOrders.OrderNumber = 1000
```

In the 2'nd query, the left join would again be pointless.

Comment: Run the code on a test to see.  I think it incorporates the comparison in the `ON` clause, but this syntax is so archaic that you should just test it yourself.

Comment: Agreed, the problem is all the environments were upgrades, sigh...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question - after finding an old environment -  thank you Gordon for the suggestion -

```
SELECT GivenName, Surname, OrderNumber
FROM Customers, SalesOrders
WHERE Customers.ID *= SalesOrders.CustomerID
and SalesOrders.OrderNumber = 1000
```

is correct and equivalent with

```
SELECT GivenName, Surname, OrderNumber
FROM Customers LEFT JOIN SalesOrders
ON Customers.ID = SalesOrders.CustomerID 
and SalesOrders.OrderNumber = 1000
```

Comment: comma is a cross join and should not be used anymore

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case all 3 code blocks will generate the same execution plan and provide same results.

`*=` means `LEFT` and `=` means `INNER`.

I assume we will never know original requirements but in this case choise of `LEFT` vs `INNER` does not depend on the `OrderNumber = 1000` condition and you have to use `LEFT` join anyway.

It is a question of readability and it is a good practice to separate filters from join conditions, espesially in cases with multiple tables joins. So just put filters in `WHERE` and join conditions in `ON` clauses just to avoid situations when you don't know "*is it a part of JOIN or WHERE*" so the last code block looks fine.

A good description of the similar situation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2510059/3441990

And you can find more about legacy join syntax here: [Old-style outer joins are obsolete](https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-prompt/finding-code-smells-using-sql-prompt-old-style-join-syntax-st001)

Comment: No, filter conditions which depend on columns being left or right joined *must* go in the `ON` clause, or you will get incorrect results