# Which is more correct with SQL Functions, Join or in Where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I know that there are similar questions floating around (like [SQL Filter criteria in join criteria or where clause which is more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1401889/550975)) but as I remember `SQL` functions are special. Maybe? So basically which is more correct/more performant?

```
SELECT *
  FROM  [DBOne].[dbo].[SomeData] SD
    INNER JOIN [DBTwo].[DBOne].[SomeOtherData_GetALL]() SOD ON SD.[DataID] = SOD.[DataID]
```

OR

```
SELECT *
  FROM  [DBOne].[dbo].[SomeData] SD
  WHERE SD.[DataID] IN (SELECT [DataID] FROM [DBTwo].[DBOne].[SomeOtherData_GetALL]())
```

Comment: Your 2 queries are not equivalent.  You are comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: As far as your particular code example goes - no, table functions are nothing special or different.

Comment: How so? I guess instead of `Left Join`, `Inner Join`...

Comment: Even if you change from `left join` to `inner join`, they can still potentially return different results.

Comment: Using the inner join, you could get duplicates from the second table and you are returning all of the values from the second table.

Comment: @sstan -- I agree with Serj -- please explain

Comment: @David: Steve Dowling just explained it.

Comment: So if my function returned `DISTINCT` then they would both return the same results

Comment: And they are equally performant?

Comment: It depends on your table structure and indexes. WHERE EXISTS will be quicker than either of them if the indexes aren't right and will be equally performant if they are. And it is more explicit in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use WHERE EXISTS instead of joining. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082449/exists-vs-join-and-use-of-exists-clause) for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is like asking `JOIN` vs `SUB QUERY`, if you are concern with the performance, i suggest to use the `JOIN` instead of using `WHERE IN` clause, you can see the difference of the performance if you use the execution plan of SQL.

To further understand, you can read this post: [Join vs. sub-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query)

Hope this help.

Comment: If this is true, then you'll get the check mark... but it seems people are saying that it doesn't matter... are you sure of this?

Comment: Actually using `SUB QUERY` is the simple and easiest way, but like what i've said if your concern is the performance itself, i am pretty sure it is better to use `JOIN` base on my experience in SQL. If you want to test you can use the execution plan of SQL for checking.